# Ubuntu command ./

Tags: command-line, paths

I was wondering What the command `./` exactly does

example:`./ts3client_runscript.sh start`

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a command, it's a location in the filesystem. `.` is the current working directory, and `/` is a path separator. What you are doing with that command, is specifying a file in the current working directory. You can do this without `./` except when you want to execute the file, so, as in the command

```
./ts3client_runscript.sh start
```

you are telling the shell to execute the file. You can execute a file that is not in the current working directory by specifying the path to it, for example `/bin/uname` as long as the file is executable, and `./` is specifying the path in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

`.` means "here".
So your command tries to execute the file `here/ts3client_runscript.sh`, that has execution permissions (so it gets executed), which accepts a parameter `start`.

Try with

```
echo "something">foo
./foo
chmod +x ./foo
./foo
```

You can see what "here" is via the command `pwd`.